# Why the assembler skips 2 memory slots between data and code segments?

Tags: assembly, memory, padding, x86-16, emu8086

I have an x86 assembly "Hello world" program and I can't figure out why the memory skips 2 slots from the "$" to the code segment. The memory address is 0710:000D for the "$" and the skip occurs at the addresses 0710:000E and 0710:000F.

I have a screenshot if that helps: [image: Screenshot from my code]

The program worked as expected but I want to learn why there is a skip in memory.

The code:

```
TITLE HELLOWORLD
    
DATA SEGMENT
    MSG DB "Hello World",10,13,"$"    
DATA ENDS

CODE SEGMENT
    START:
    MOV AX, DATA
    MOV DS, AX     
    
    LEA DX, MSG
    MOV AH, 9
    INT 21H
    
    MOV AH, 4CH
    INT 21H 
    
CODE ENDS

END START
```

This is assembled into a DOS .EXE executable, not a .COM.

Comment: Alignment. Segments start at 16 byte boundaries.

Comment: Please include the code as text in the question, not as an image.